# Get inbound ip adress from azurerm_windows_web_app in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create `azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule` resource witch allows IP of "Azure windows web app".

When I write it manually it works fine. f.e.:

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule" "api_cloud" {
  name             = var.cloud_firewal_rule_name
  server_id        = azurerm_mssql_server.api.id
  start_ip_address = "00.000.000.00"
  end_ip_address   = "00.000.000.00"
}
```

I want to get IP address like this `start_ip_address/end_ip_address  = azurerm_windows_web_app.api.inbound_ip_address`.

But there isn't inbound option in `azurerm_windows_web_app`, I can only access outbound addresses `azurerm_windows_web_app.api.outbound_ip_addresses`.

Is there is anyway do something like this?

---

IN SHORT:
How to get this IP address with terraform?
[image]

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you would like to grant your App Service access to an MS SQL database by creating a azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule? If yes, you only have to whitelist the outbound addresses of that App Service.

Comment: Yes, correctly. And I want to whitelist it in terraform itself, not in Az Portal or some devops pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is but it's a bit complicated due to the way Terraform works. I used a Linux App Service in my examples but it should work identically for both Windows and Linux versions. Let's go:

So, things are a bit more complicated due to the fact that App Services have quite a big range of possible outbound IP addresses as they are running on a shared infrastructure. Therefore it returns a list with an unknown length. That makes things annoying for Terraform. As an example, this is how you usually iterate through multiple items in Terraform using [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each):

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule" "example" {
   for_each         = toset(azurerm_linux_web_app.api_app.outbound_ip_address_list)
   name             = "FirewallRule"
   server_id        = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
   start_ip_address = each.key
   end_ip_address   = each.key
}
```

In this snippet, you take the list of outbound IP addresses from the App Service, [cast them to a set](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/toset), and then iterate through it. However, this only works if the App Service already exists - if you are starting from an empty slate, you will face the following error:

> azurerm_linux_web_app.api_app.outbound_ip_address_list is a list of
> string, known only after apply
>
> The "for_each" map includes keys
> derived from resource attributes that cannot be determined until
> apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the full set of keys that
> will identify the instances of this resource.
>
> When working with
> unknown values in for_each, it's better to define the map keys
> statically in your configuration and place apply-time results only in
> the map values.
>
> Alternatively, you could use the -target
> planning option to first apply only the resources that the for_each
> value depends on, and then apply a second time to fully converge.

Luckily Terraform has a quite helpful error message, which tells us how we can work around the problem. Using the [-target parameter](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/plan#resource-targeting) we can first create the App Service like this

```
terraform apply -target=azurerm_linux_web_app.api_app
```

This should only create the App Service and dependencies required by it. Afterward, we can then execute Terraform normally and it should work as desired without any errors. It's not very pretty, but currently, there are no better ways of achieving exactly what you want.

Comment: I did as you wrote here, terraform whitelisted outbound IPs just fine. But I still can't access DB. I think I need to whitelist the inbound IP to make this work.

Comment: DB Error message: SqlException: Cannot open server 'somedb' requested by the login. Client with IP address 'someIP' is not allowed to access the server. To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.